# How can i copy a name from a file with spaces in and create a new file with this name

Tags: batch-file, rename

I am after a batch file to convert two files with the same name but different extensions
ie

```
test file.dat
test file.txt
```

I want to combine these files with a seperator (I have used ~)

I want the new file to be named a new extension but keep the original name, I have managed this but the majority of the files I use have spaces in them and I can get it to work with the spaces

The code I have so far:

```
type *.dat > new.andy
echo. >> new.andy
echo ~ >> new.andy
type *.txt >> new.andy
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.dat') do set FileName=%%~na
REN new.andy %FileName%.andy
```

So far I have got the script to work apart from to rename the file with its full name including spaces, up to now it only goes till first space ie test.andy

Comment: Have tried adding quotes around the filenames in the `REN` statement?  If a filename has a space in it, you must enclose it in quotes.

Comment: Yes I have sorted it now thanks all I had tried quotes but had delimiter set to space so once I added "delims=" in my for statement it worked many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Test the following

```
type "*.dat" > new.andy
echo. >> new.andy
echo ~ >> new.andy
type "*.txt" >> new.andy
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.dat') do set FileName=%%~na
REN new.andy %FileName%.andy
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b *.dat') do (
  type "%%a" >  "%%~na.andy"
  echo.      >> "%%~na.andy"
  echo ~     >> "%%~na.andy"
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b *.txt') do (
  type "%%a" >> "%%~na.andy"
)
```

This will combine all `*.dat` files with all `*.txt` files, and the name of the combined file will be `.andy`.

Depending on what you are after and how your files are organized, this can be improved.